# Canvas is cleared on calling context.fill()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw few lines in the canvas and the path is closed. After drawing the lines, a new set of lines(it can be a closed path) are drawn with new transform matrix and the fillRule is "evenodd". When the fill() method is called by the context of the canvas, the lines drawn before is cleared. How can I render the lines without clearing the canvas with fill? I have also tried saving[context.save()] and restoring[context.restore()] the canvas graphics. It is not working. Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your whole working code.

Comment: Sorry @HirenJungi, I don't have a sample code. I can't share the working code due to security reasons.

Comment: If you can't share your code , it's difficult for me to find out where exactly problem occurs and it becomes really difficult to debug.

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is without some code. But at a guess I would say you are forgetting to start each set of shapes you draw with `ctx.beginPath()` So its `ctx.beginPath();`  define your lines then draw them `ctx.stroke()`  then `ctx.beginPath();` define your fill shape `ctx.fill()` If you dont use ctx.beginPath the canvas API will redraw everything you have defined. `ctx.beginPath()` removes all previous shapes you have defined.

Comment: Do you set ctx.globalCompositeOperation="copy" ? This value clear graphic automatically on painting.